Encrypting a file in chunks using AES-GCM
I want to write a generator that encrypts a file in chunks of given size and returns the chunks one-by-one. I also want to authenticate the payload hence I have chosen AES-GCM for this.
Why am I encrypting in chunks rather than an entire file at once? I am sending these chunks over a network so rather than encrypting an entire (potentially large) file, storing it elsewhere and then chunking it again while making the network transfer, I am encrypting a single chunk that is to be transferred and immediately sending it over the network.
However I am quite unsure if the way I've implemented this is correct and I couldn't find any useful documentation for my use case.
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
import struct

CHUNK_SIZE = 32
AES_BLOCK_SIZE = 16

def encryptFileInChunks(key: bytes, infile: str, file_size: int):
    iv = Random.new.read(16)
    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, iv, mac_len=16)

    with open(infile, 'r') as infile:
        # write the original file size as little endian 8 byte int
        # so that we can remove the padding after decryption by
        # truncating to this original length
        yield struct.pack("<Q", file_size)
        # iv for decryption
        yield iv

    while True:
        chunk = infile.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
        if len(chunk) == 0:
            break
        if len(chunk) % AES_BLOCK_SIZE != 0:
            # add padding to make a valid block
            chunk += b" " * (AES_BLOCK_SIZE - len(chunk) % AES_BLOCK_SIZE)
        
        c, d = encryptor.encrypt_and_digest(chunk)

        # only return ciphertext
        yield c, None
    
    # first tuple value being None indicates end of ciphertext,
    # return the mac
    yield None, d

Will this correctly calculate the MAC over the entire payload as described by the GCM mode or am I only returning the MAC over the final chunk? How can I calculate the MAC over the entire ciphertext normally in a similar way, without having to send the (ciphertext, mac) pair individually for each chunk?
I guess another way would be to just use AES-CBC and use some sort of a HMAC to authenticate seperately, but that would add a little bit of overhead and using GCM makes things a lot faster.

encrypt() does not return a tag, only encrypt_and_digest() does. Chunk-by-chunk processing can be realized with multiple encrypt() calls in conjunction with a final encrypt_and_digest() call that returns the tag (for the entire ciphertext). Such an implementation (naturally) has the disadvantage that all chunks are required for authentication (i.e. if the first chunk is corrupted, this is only revealed when the last chunk is processed). Note: GCM does not require padding, the recommended GCM nonce size is 12 bytes.

My bad the encrypt() part was a typo. What you said makes sense, I'm using this to encrypt (potentially large) files and currently the file is completely recieved, decrypted and only then it's digest is compared. Theres potential for a speedup by sending the digest for every chunk and making the decryption chunk-by-chunk as well, checking the digest each time, at the cost of sending upto 16 additional MAC bytes per chunk.

@Topaco so what you're saying is that the MAC is internally updated with the data passed to every call to encrypt() without having to explicitly call encrypt_and_digest()? I wouldn't have assumed that, thanks for the clarification!
